# Preprocessor reserved keywords

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

For macros, are there any name limitations other than it needs to be an identifier? For example, would something like the following be valid?

```
#define assert getchar
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    assert();
}
```

Code link: https://godbolt.org/z/ra63na.

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 0
        call    getchar
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

And does the preprocessor have any knowledge of the C language? Or is it more like a find-and-replace program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For macros, are there any name limitations other than it needs to be an identifier?

Yes, they are subject to the provisions of section 7.1.3 of the language specification ("Reserved Identifiers"), in particular:

> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use
>   [including as macro names].
>
> [...]
>
> - Each macro name in any of the [standard library specification] subclauses (including the future library directions) is reserved for
>   use as specified if any of its associated headers is included; unless
>   explicitly stated otherwise
>
> [...]
>
> - Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the [standard library specification] subclauses (including the future library
>   directions) is reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier
>   with file scope in the same name space if any of its associated
>   headers is included.
>
> [...] If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in
> which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a
> reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

The second bullet point in particular would be relevant to your example code if it also included the `assert.h` header.  The identifier `assert` would then reserved for use as a macro name.  That you use it as one would trigger undefined behavior.  That does not place any particular requirements on the implementation -- in fact that's exactly the meaning of "undefined behavior".  It does not require the implementation to accept the code, nor to reject it, nor to emit any kind of diagnostic in either case.  If it did accept it, the preprocessor would not be required to perform macro substitution on `assert`, nor would it be forbidden to do so, nor, in fact, would it be required to behave in a way that seems in any way rational or predictable.

Similar would apply based on the third bullet point if you defined `getchar` as a macro name in code that includes `stdio.h`, as the example does.  The code actually presented is ok, however.

You also ask,

> And does the preprocessor have any knowledge of the C language? Or is
> it more like a find-and-replace program?

A little.  The C preprocessor is not a general-purpose macro language, and attempts to use it as one often go poorly.  The preprocessor's input is a series of tokens, determined according to rules consistent with C syntax, and it uses the same syntax for identifiers that C does.  Conditional inclusion directives recognize a subset of the arithmetic expressions of C, and they work in terms of one of the host implementation's integer data types.  The preprocessor (or at least the tokenization stage preceding it) understands C string literals and character constants, so macro replacement does not affect the contents of these.

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in section 7.1.2 and 7.1.3 of the standard (C11). Here is a selection of rules pertaining to macros:

- If used, a header shall be included outside of any external declaration or definition, and it shall first be included before the first reference to any of the functions or objects it declares, or to any of the types or macros it defines.
- The program shall not have any macros with names lexically identical to keywords currently defined prior to the inclusion of the header or when any macro defined in the header is expanded.
- Each macro name in any of the following subclauses (including the future library
  directions) is reserved for use as specified if any of its associated headers is included;
  unless explicitly stated otherwise.
- Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the following subclauses (including the
  future library directions) is reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with
  file scope in the same name space if any of its associated headers is included.

So the exact program you posted is correct, since `<assert.h>` has not been included. But it would be undefined behaviour if you did include that header.

Answer (score 1):

It's really dumb. It understands enough to do token replacement, but not much more.

For example: `#define test fail` will replace `test` in `test(...)` but not `tested` or `"test"`.

Since C has a very basic syntax writing a parser that can work through and identify tokens like that is actually not that hard. Making it understand the totality of C syntax is beyond the scope of that tool.

In other words, for an input program like:

```c
#define test fail

int main() {
  test(9, "test", tested());

  return 0;
}
```

The C pre-processor breaks this up into tokens that end up something like:

```c
[ "#", "define", "test", "fail" ]

[ "int", "main", "(", ")", "{" ]
[ "test", "(", "9", "\"test\"", "tested", "(", ")", ")", ";" ]
...
```

Where each of those is processed using the simple pre-processor grammar.

This is slightly more complicated because macros can include arguments, but you get the idea. The grammar used is a simple subset of the whole C grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is valid.  No the pre-processor is not language aware.  The pre-processor does exactly what it is told - included content, replaces macros - if that results in invalid syntax, the compiler must detect that.

Other then C symbol naming rules, there are no C language dependencies or reserved words.  All pre-processor directives start `#` which is not a valid C symbol name so there is no need for reserved words.

The pre-processor can be run on its own - either by command line option to the compiler driver or in the of the GUN tool chain it is a standalone executable `cpp` - making it useful for purposes other than just C and C++ source pre-processing.

Comment: It's not a requirement of the standard that the preprocessor be able to run on its own -- this is just a common tooling setup .  The preprocessor behaviour is defined by the language standard so it's not really clear what you mean by saying it is "not language aware". The C preprocessor is different to the C++ preprocessor, and there are several rules about reserved identifiers in preprocessor macros

Comment: @Clifford -- I can't think of an example of how `cpp` could be useful outside of C. What would be an example of a use case for using the `cpp` outside c preprocessing?

Comment: @David542, the C preprocessor has historically been used as a preprocessor for some other languages with sufficient syntactic similarity.  Fortran in particular.

Comment: @David542 :Really? Anywhere  you want to insert the content of one file in another (`#include`) or replace a macro parametrically with some other text (`#define`) or confitionally include or execluse sections of text (`#if` / `#elif`/ `#endif`):  makefiles, assembler code, the applications are numerous.  It is just a text pre-processor, there is nothing specific to C in it.  Tools like `sed` or `AWK` may be more appropriate in some cases, but the is a learning curve to those.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  I am not sure that "syntactic similarity" is even necessary.  It need not even be a programming language.  It pretty much just has to be text.  One caveat is that the `#` at the start of a line preceded by zero or more whitespace is reserved so nothing that already uses `#` in that way.

Comment: @Clifford, I agree that the preprocessor's input does not need to be expressed in a programming language.  I was giving a real-world example.  I would also say that one is more likely to run into issues with divergent syntax when the input *is* a programming language than when it is, say, English-language text.  But you might run into issues with text in other languages, because the preprocessor is not required to recognize or accept characters outside the C implementation's source character set.

Comment: @JohnBollinger : I read your answer and your comment, and accept your points.